# rpm doesn't work and gets an error

Tags: fedora, rhel, rpm

I typed `sudo rpm install` into my terminal and then I got following error :

`error: missing ':' (found 0x00) at /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/rpmrc:1`

how can I solve that?

Comment: If you'd like us to reproduce your problem, please include information on which RHEL you're running (`cat /etc/redhat-release`, do a `uname -a`, which rpm version you've got `rpm --version`). Also, are you actually running `sudo rpm install` (which doesn't do very much) or are you installing a specific RPM? If so, include that info.

Comment: @Edward I use fedora30 and my RPM vesion is 4.14.2.1

Comment: Please edit your question and add: output of `uname -a` and `rpm -qa|grep rpm|sort` and please answer my question about the exact invocation.

Comment: @Edward rpm -qa|grep rpm|sort output is the error that i said in question and the uname -a output is : Linux localhost.localdomain 5.1.7-300.fc30.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 5 12:32:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

The `/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/rpmrc` file is part of the `redhat-rpm-config` package, which is a package that provides customized Red Hat macros used during the building of RPM packages. Unless you are building Red Hat RPMs on your system, I think it is safe to run `dnf remove redhat-rpm-config` to get rid of the (probably invalid) `rpmrc` file.

Comment: I received that error for dnf too.

Comment: OK. Try manually renaming the rpmrc file: `mv  /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/rpmrc /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/rpmrc.bak` and then running dnf remove redhat-rpm-config